# Meaning of 'not permitted in A or in B'

Tags: grammar, american-english, vocabulary, sentence, language-formation

Does "not permitted in A or in B" mean "not permitted in A and not permitted in B" or mean "not permitted in A or not permitted in B"?

Thanks for any helpful answers!

Comment: English is not algebra. There is no generic answer. Ask whoever wrote the actual text you are interpreting.

Comment: It is ambiguous. That said, in the absence of more context, most people would probably interpret the *or* as having priority, that is, *not (A or B)*, which is *(not A) and (not B)*.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, it would probably indicate the first option. That is, "Not permitted in (A or B)"; being in either A or B would be a violation of the rule; and indeed, !(A or B) = (!A) and (!B).

The problem with the second interpretation is that it would be ambiguous about exactly what was being prohibited (does the listener get to choose one of A or B to avoid?), and so would not be a useful piece of communication.

Answer (score 0):

Context of the phrase is not clear. However, to me it seems.

**"It is neither permitted in A nor in B"**.